# What's the difference between globalDependencies and globalDevDependencies in typings.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

There are `globalDependencies` and `globalDevDependencies` in typings.json.

When used in my project, the typing definitions worked with Typescript files even when I swap typings between the 2 categories.

What's the real difference between the 2 categories and how can I know in which category should I put a package's typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are globalDependencies and globalDevDependencies in typings.json.

Lets call your package `foo`. If someone does an `typigns install` on a package that uses `foo` they get `globalDependencies`. If some does `typings install` *in* `foo` they get both.

Comment: Am I right to understand as: if someone npm installs a package that depends on `foo`, the `foo` typings to be put under `globalDependencies`? And if someone npm installs the `foo` package directly, the `foo` typings to get into both `globalDevDependecies` and `globalDependencies`? I actually just notice that they have their non-global counterparts too! It's kinda confusing...

Comment: `And if someone npm installs the foo package directly` no. If someone clones `foo` and runs `typings install` in it. I've fixed it.